# How to navigate to different page which is different project in same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have xamarin solution. I wanted to add register login sqlite functionality in my solution. So I found a solution on internet. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-using-sqlite-database/

The example I found is great. However, once the user has logged in; it just prompts 'Login Successful'. It does not take me to next page.

I have added the register login code in my solution.

Once user is logged in; I would like App to go to page which is in same solution but in different project.

This below code is under Photos.Android->MainActivity.

I want app to take user to Photos->MainPage.xaml page.

See image. 
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwk1A.png)

```
        private void Btnsign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3"); //Call Database  
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
            var data = db.Table<LoginTable>(); //Call Table  
            var data1 = data.Where(x => x.username == txtusername.Text && x.password == txtPassword.Text).FirstOrDefault(); //Linq Query  
            if (data1 != null)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                //StartActivity(typeof(PhotoMain));
                //Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPhotoPage());

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Username or Password invalid", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

I have commented out 2 lines. I have tried these line but didn't work.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an Xamarin.Forms based application or a native Xamarin.Android application? (I'm seeing a mix within your question)

Comment: You are mixing Android and Forms code.  This works, but I wouldn't suggest it, particularly if you are a beginner.  It would be better to implement your login in the common Forms project than in the Android project.

Comment: It should be xamarin forms application. I had my existing solution but i wanted to add register login functionality,

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Forms project? If yes why are you adding this code in MainActivity? You can have a SQLite database in xamarin forms FYI

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

Comment: Although it is xamarin project but it will ob ONLY USED ON ANDROIDS.  so Its doesnt need to be cross platform anymore. It will never be used on IOS.

Comment: If you are writing your UI in XAML (Xamarin Forms) then write ALL of your UI in XAML, including your login page.  Otherwise just write the whole thing as a Xamarin Android (not Forms) project.